# How to clear Django RQ jobs from a queue?

Tags: django, python-rq

I feel a bit stupid for asking, but it doesn't appear to be in the [documentation for RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/). I have a 'failed' queue with thousands of items in it and I want to clear it using the Django admin interface. The admin interface lists them and allows me to delete and re-queue them individually but I can't believe that I have to dive into the django shell to do it in bulk.

What have I missed?

Comment: If anyone looking for a solution specific to **django-rq>=2.0.0**. [This link](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/964) can help.

Answer (score 17):

The `Queue` class has an `empty()` method that can be accessed like:

```
import django_rq
q = django_rq.get_failed_queue()
q.empty()
```

However, in my tests, that only cleared the failed list key in Redis, not the job keys itself. So your thousands of jobs would still occupy Redis memory. To prevent that from happening, you must remove the jobs individually:

```
import django_rq
q = django_rq.get_failed_queue()
while True:
    job = q.dequeue()
    if not job:
        break
    job.delete()  # Will delete key from Redis
```

As for having a button in the admin interface, you'd have to change `django-rq/templates/django-rq/jobs.html` template, who extends `admin/base_site.html`, and doesn't seem to give any room for customizing.

Comment: That second snippet is huge, couldn't figure out why we were having a memory leak with leftover keys until that. For anyone that has already dequeued the jobs like I had (and therefore lost access to the keys via python-rq), use the conn = redis.from_url(redis_url); conn.keys() method to get them back for deletion.

Comment: @CharlesOffenbacher  I'm not quite sure if I understand the snippets above.  Are you saying that we need to run both of the code snippets above but run the second snippet first and the first snippet second?  Thanks.

Comment: @Robert I believe you should use the second snippet only. The first code snippet only clears the list that keeps track of failed jobs, not the actual failed jobs themselves.

Comment: This is no longer working in **django-rq==2.1.0**. There is a change as mentioned in [this post](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/964). I tried to use as per the new code changes but getting errors.. Have also put a comment on the same post for proper use. Hope will get a solution soon..

Comment: I've created a Django management command to do bulk deletes of failed Django RQ jobs. The GitHub gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/jbarham/de89f85e900bf5f3adce3f0e4d65c5d9).

Answer (score 2):

The redis-cli allows FLUSHDB, great for my local environment as I generate a bizzallion jobs.

With a working Django integration I will update. Just adding $0.02.

Comment: Won't this affect non-failed jobs?

Comment: Any idea why existing jobs would jump back into the queue once I restart my django and redis server after calling flushdb?

Comment: @Joe in general yes, current jobs will go away.

Comment: @andyzinsser - I have had Python scripts running that would queue more jobs (one option). Also, you could have a stack of Python to call (FIFO backlog) - with a clear queue more marches in... RQ is somewhat a blackbox, when I wanted to clear **100% for sure** I would stop all Python processes (restart) and when the service was down flush and clear. Remember, you can "query" for jobs and processes to learn more about what is happening. I learn more everyday.

Answer (score 1):

You can empty any queue by name using following code sample:

```
import django_rq

queue = "default"
q = django_rq.get_queue(queue)
q.empty()
```

or even have Django Command for that:

```
import django_rq

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("-q", "--queue", type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        q = django_rq.get_queue(options.get("queue"))
        q.empty()
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are outdated with the RQ updates implementing `Registries`.

Now, you need to do this to loop through and delete **failed** jobs. This would work any particular `Registry` as well.

```
import django_rq
from rq.registry import FailedJobRegistry

failed_registry = FailedJobRegistry('default', connection=django_rq.get_connection())

for job_id in failed_registry.get_job_ids():
    try:
        failed_registry.remove(job_id, delete_job=True)
    except:
        # failed jobs expire in the queue. There's a
        # chance this will raise NoSuchJobError
        pass
```

[Source](https://python-rq.org/docs/job_registries/)

Answer (score 0):

As @augusto-men method seems not to work anymore, here is another solution:

You can use the the **raw connection** to delete the failed jobs. Just iterate over rq:job keys and check the job status.

```
from django_rq import get_connection
from rq.job import Job

# delete failed jobs
con = get_connection('default')
for key in con.keys('rq:job:*'):
    job_id = key.decode().replace('rq:job:', '')
    job = Job.fetch(job_id, connection=con)
    if job.get_status() == 'failed':
        con.delete(key)
con.delete('rq:failed:default')  # reset failed jobs registry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty a queue from the command line with:

`rq empty [queue-name]`

Running `rq info` will list  all the queues.